# Using JavaFX to build a GUI for an ATM but having trouble getting primary stage to change scene

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scene, stage

Trying to use event handlers to sync specific button pushes to advance to the next "screen" on an ATM by: hiding the stage, updating the stage with the scene that a button push creates, and then reshowing the stage.

I am curious if this process can only be taken so deep since my button for newCheckingsAccounts isn't doing anything like it should, but I can go backwards on that page and I used the same code more or less to try to keep going forward.

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestAccount extends Application {

//creates arrays that will store the accounts
ArrayList<Account> Checking = new ArrayList<Account>(); 
ArrayList<Integer> Savings = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//declares variables
double interest = 0;
double interestRate = 0;
double balance = 0;
double credit = 0;
double initialBalance = 0;
double feeChargedPerTransaction = 0;
Button btMain = new Button("Go Back to Main Menu");
Button btNewAccount = new Button("Make New Account");
Button btExistingAccount = new Button("Access an Existing Account");
Button btNewCheckings = new Button("Make New Checkings");
Button btNewSavings = new Button("Make New Savings");

@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

// Hold two buttons in an HBox
HBox hBox = new HBox();
hBox.setSpacing(10);
hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
Button btGoToAccounts = new Button("Go To Accounts Page");
Button btEnd = new Button("End Program");
hBox.getChildren().add(btGoToAccounts);
hBox.getChildren().add(btEnd);

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.CENTER);

// Create a scene and place it in the stage
Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 300);
primaryStage.setTitle("Bank of America"); // Set the stage title
primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

// creates and registers handler and specifies action for button to go to accounts page
btGoToAccounts.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        primaryStage.hide();

        // Hold three buttons in an HBox
        HBox hBox1 = new HBox();
        hBox1.setSpacing(10);
        hBox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox1.getChildren().add(btNewAccount);
        hBox1.getChildren().add(btExistingAccount);
        hBox1.getChildren().add(btMain);

        BorderPane borderPane1 = new BorderPane();
        borderPane1.setBottom(hBox1);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox1, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(borderPane1, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Accounts Page"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
}); 

// creates and registers handler and specifies action for button to go to create new accounts page
btNewAccount.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        primaryStage.hide();

        // Hold three buttons in an HBox
        HBox hBox2 = new HBox();
        hBox2.setSpacing(10);
        hBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button btNewCheckings = new Button("Make New Checkings");
        Button btNewSavings = new Button("Make New Savings");
        hBox2.getChildren().add(btNewCheckings);
        hBox2.getChildren().add(btNewSavings);
        hBox2.getChildren().add(btMain);

        BorderPane borderPane2 = new BorderPane();
        borderPane2.setBottom(hBox2);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox2, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene2 = new Scene(borderPane2, 800, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("New Accounts"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
});

// THIS IS THE BUTTON THAT DOESN'T REGISTER AS BEING CLICKED...havent done the newSavingsAccount button either.want it to take me to new scene where i enter in new account info hit submit and then take me back to the main menu ("scene")
 btNewCheckings.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        HBox hbox3 = new HBox();
        Scene scene3 = new Scene(hbox3, 800, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene3); // Place the scene in the stage

        //the Name text field
        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setPromptText("Enter the desired account name which will be used under the access an existing account screen later");
        name.setPrefColumnCount(10);
        name.getText();
        hbox3.getChildren().add(name);

        //Defining the initial balance/fee text fields
        final TextField initialBalance = new TextField();
        final TextField fee = new TextField();
        initialBalance.setPromptText("Enter your desired initial balance as a double.");
        fee.setPromptText("Enter the agreed upon fee per transaction as a double.");

        initialBalance.setPrefColumnCount(15);
        fee.setPrefColumnCount(15);
        fee.getText();
        hbox3.getChildren().add(fee);
        initialBalance.getText();
        hbox3.getChildren().add(initialBalance);

        //Defining the Submit button
        Button accountCreation = new Button("Create the Account");
        hbox3.getChildren().add(accountCreation);

        //Defining the Clear button
        Button clear = new Button("Clear");
        hbox3.getChildren().add(clear);

        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

        //Setting an action for the Submit button
        accountCreation.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                if ((initialBalance.getText() != null && !initialBalance.getText().isEmpty())) {
                    CheckingAccount newMember = new CheckingAccount();
                    newMember.setInitialBalance(Double.parseDouble(initialBalance.toString()));
                    newMember.setFee((Double.parseDouble(fee.toString())));
                    Checking.add(newMember);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("no member added");
                }
             }
         });

        //Setting an action for the Clear button
        clear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                name.clear();
                initialBalance.clear();
            }
        });

    }
});

// creates and registers handler and specifies action for end button to close the stage
btEnd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        primaryStage.close();
    }
});


// creates and registers handler and specifies action for main menu button to go to first scene
btMain.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        primaryStage.hide();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bank of America"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
});

  }

   /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think removing the overriding of your both buttons in the btNewAccount.setOnAction() should solve your problem:

```
// creates and registers handler and specifies action for button to go
    // to create new accounts page
    btNewAccount.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            primaryStage.hide();

            // Hold three buttons in an HBox
            HBox hBox2 = new HBox();
            hBox2.setSpacing(10);
            hBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            // ############### removed this ###################
            //Button btNewCheckings = new Button("Make New Checkings");
            //Button btNewSavings = new Button("Make New Savings");
            hBox2.getChildren().add(btNewCheckings);
            hBox2.getChildren().add(btNewSavings);
            hBox2.getChildren().add(btMain);

            BorderPane borderPane2 = new BorderPane();
            borderPane2.setBottom(hBox2);
            BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox2, Pos.CENTER);

            Scene scene2 = new Scene(borderPane2, 400, 300);
            primaryStage.setTitle("New Accounts"); // Set the stage title

            primaryStage.setScene(scene2); // Place the scene in the stage
            primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
        }
    });
```

If you want to instantiate in an ActionHandler of a Button, you need to declare it's ActionHandler in the same Block.

The way you did it (ActionHandler in the start method), it will only work, if you use your class atributes (Buttons) which you have initialized at the top.

Hope I could help :)

Edit: Probably a good tip for this project is looking at FXML files with JavaFX. This might help you: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/

Comment: Thanks didn't catch that!